# error connect to server

Tags: sql-server

> Cannot connect to GUARDIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinityinstaller/content/installermaster/tkenablenamedpipesandtcpipconnections.htm

Comment: See my answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49421/2718

Answer (score 1):

Check if SQL Server browser service is running.

Also enable network protocol TCP set it to default.