# Error trying to open database

Tags: sql-server

The database is for ms exchange. I am getting the following error. Any ideas guys?[image]

Comment: Can you show or describe what's in SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Services on the machine `LRSERVER`? This should show you the default and named instances on that machine, and whether the services are started. Next would be SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for `<instance>` > and making sure that named pipes and/or TCP/IP is enabled. After that would be checking your firewall and making sure that the right ports are open. Etc. etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access a SQL Server database from other computer connected to the same workgroup?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48667/how-to-access-a-sql-server-database-from-other-computer-connected-to-the-same-wo)

Comment: @JonSeigel - Bit different. This is a hidden instance to discourage people from connecting to it directly. Connecting to `\\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query` might work. [Some details here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/255490-How-to-connect-MICROSOFTSSEE)

Comment: @MartinSmith Nice, didn't know SSEE did this...

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to one of these issues:

- A DNS problem: Your workstation does not ping the IP address associated with this host. resolution: Try to ping the LRSERVER. If it does not ping properly, add the LRSERVER ip address in your host file.
- A firewall issue: the network traffic between your workstation and the SQL Server instance goes through a firewall which blocks the ports required by SQL Server. resolution: Ask the firewall administrator to open the required ports.