# How do I make SQL Server database accessible to PC's on the LAN?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on server machine with instance name `abc12`. This instance contains two databases:

1. alarm
2. report

but when we connect to the `abc12` instance from other PC's on the local area network, it shows only one database `alarm` in this instance. It doesn't show the `report` database.

How do I make that `report` database accessible to other PC's on the LAN?

Please help me

Comment: You don't specify if you are on domain or workgroup but similar question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48667/507

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an issue with permissions - if one database is visible they've clearly connected to the instance. I'd suggest you run SSMS as yourself from the other PC and see what happens.

Comment: sir what is ssms?

Comment: SSMS = [SQL Server Management Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx). What are you using now to connect to the instance, when you're observing you don't see the report database?

Comment: Odd - I didn't see the comment until now. Blaž is right, I meant the application you're using to connect. It doesn't even have to be SSMS, it could be whatever application is being used.

Answer (score 0):

In simple word, [SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx) is a client to login in SQL Server.

Now to answer you question as it is already mentioned it seems to be a permission issue, You can check with permission given to the user to.

VIEW ANY DATABASE permissions is by default public, you can grant this permission with below query

```
GRANT VIEW ANY DATABASE TO loginName;
```

Check [GRANT DataBase Permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178569.aspx) to assign more permission to user.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to confirm this being a permissions issue is a/b testing on both your machine and the users. Log in as both users on both machines and you'll have definitive proof.